# Filtering a .csv in D3 by two variables

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a CSV which is shaped like the one below. I want to filter the data from the CSV so that I only get the hair colour and value for one country and for a specfic help group.

```
Help,Hair Colour,Europe,Africa,North America
1Male,Brown Hair,1,13,14
1Male,Blonde Hair,3,20,24
1Male,Ginger Hair,50,30,30
1Male,Grey Hair,70,40,40
1Male,Black Hair,100,100,100
1Female,Brown Hair,66,22,14
1Female,Blonde Hair,70,45,23
1Female,Ginger Hair,80,46,25
1Female,Grey Hair,90,70,30
1Female,Black Hair,100,100,100
```

For example I would want to define that I only want 1Female in North America:

```
Hair Colour,North America
Brown Hair,14
Blonde Hair,23
Ginger Hair,25
Grey Hair,30
Black Hair,100
```

I would then want to store each of these hair colours as their own variable, as I will to generate a random number from 1-100 and assign a hair colour based on whether the value is greater than or equal to the random number.

I have been reading the .csv in with D3 and know there is a filter option but I don't know how to filter by two variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [d3.js filter from csv file using multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156864/d3-js-filter-from-csv-file-using-multiple-columns)

Comment: That's very easy to do, but here is my advice: don't do that. You already lost time/resources loading and parsing that CSV. Therefore, the best idea is just keeping it the way it is, and using only the columns you want in the dataviz. If you try to filter some columns out (which means deleting some properties from each object in the array) you will only add more unnecessary tasks for the browser to execute. A way better idea is changing the CSV itself

Comment: Here is another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44858992/5768908